# How can you list all file objects loaded in IPFS?

Tags: ipfs

I can add recursively a bunch of files within IPFS with 
$ ipfs add -r data/

How can I get a list back of all loaded file objects [in a specific directory]?  Similar to aws s3 listObjects...

The ipfs file ls command does not seem to be recursive.  I understand that I can call the API a thousand times but that does not seem to be very efficient.

I must be missing something here.
Thanks,
Pat.

Answer (score 6):

IPFS is based on [Merkle tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree), so you can display all elements under your root resource. You can use:

- web ui: `http://localhost:8080/ipfs/<your_root_resource_hash>`
- graphmd: `https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmNZiPk974vDsPmQii3YbrMKfi12KTSNM7XMiYyiea4VYZ/example#/ipfs/QmRFTtbyEp3UaT67ByYW299Suw7HKKnWK6NJMdNFzDjYdX/graphmd/README.md`
- shell commands:

  - `ipfs ls <your_root_resource_hash>`
  - `ipfs refs -r <your_root_resource_hash>`

Docs for [ipfs files ls](https://ipfs.io/docs/commands/#ipfs-files-ls)

edit : More important, your directory name is not persisted into IPFS. You can access your resource knowing its hash, the one you get when you add it with `ipfs add -r <your_dir>`

Comment: But can you get all sub-resources in one command?... like ipfs ls -r <dir>

Comment: Sorry but I still fail to see the -r option

Comment: hi Pat could you try type this :

Comment: `ipfs refs -r /ipfs/QmW2WQi7j6c7UgJTarActp7tDNikE4B2qXtFCfLPdsgaTQ` and could you precise the ipfs version use ? `ipfs version` i use 0.4.4

Comment: edit : try this hash ipfs/QmYwAPJzv5CZsnA625s3Xf2nemtYgPpHdWEz79ojWnPbdG instead of QmW2WQi7j6c7UgJTarActp7tDNikE4B2qXtFCfLPdsgaTQ

Answer (score 3):

You can use this command to list all objects

```
ipfs files ls
```

Comment: What's the difference between this and `ipfs filestore ls`, as others have suggested? When might this be preferred?

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in local files added with something like `ipfs add -r --nocopy /files`, what you want is

```
ipfs filestore ls
```

Unfortunately now this lists blocks instead of whole files, see https://github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs/issues/5293

Answer (score 0):

you can use the command:

```
ipfs filestore ls
```